# NDK for beginner : where/how to add source files?

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface

I'm trying to use the NDK, and I've been working with official samples to get started. I've managed to get the "Hello JNI" sample working :
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-jni

(I work with Android Studio)

But I don't know how to add source files to the project. So, for example, the JNI function provided is (I removed macros that aren't useful for this) :

```
jstring Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                                                  jobject thiz )
{
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI !");
}
```

Let's say I want to get the string from a C function "getString()", defined as below:

```
const char* getString()
{
    return "Hello from getString()";
}

//Then, JNI function becomes

jstring Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                                                  jobject thiz )
{
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, getString());
}
```

If I create a getString.h where I declare the function, and put the implementation in my current and only one source file, everything works like a charm. So, headers do work.

However, If I create a GetString.c file where I put the implementation, my code stops compiling. I do understand it's because GetString.o doesn't get linked (or even compiled ? I don't know), but I have no idea about how to tell Android Studio to compile both hello-jni.c (sample's source fil) and GetString.c

Should I get my hands dirty and modify gradle files ? 
I also heard about a file called Android.mk which acts like a makefile, but I haven't found it in the project. If it's mandatory, should I create it, and what to put in it ? If it's not, how does the IDE knows he must build hello-jni.c ? (AKA "how did the project get configured before I modified it")

If you need any information about java-side things or gradle scripts, just have a look on the github link :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, a bit of testing was enough to confirm what I thought. I just had to create Android.mk :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-jni.c, GetString.cpp
LOCAL_MODULE    := hello-jni

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```